# Using time to seed the randomizer in C with loops

Tags: c, loops, random, random-seed

I am using `srand((unsigned)time(NULL))` to seed the randomizer in my C program. I noticed that when I create an array of random numbers using loops, all of the numbers will be the same if I put the seeder inside the loop instead of outside the loop. I assume this is because the loop runs extremely fast, but how does the seeder work to reseed the randomizer when it is outside of the loop? I am confused about how this is working in the program.

Answer (score 4):

You should only `srand` once in your program. 
Because `time(NULL)` is measured in seconds, inside a loop you are actually seeding the same value over and over. 
Each seed will produce a deterministic stream of pseudo-random numbers, but setting the same seed twice produces the same sequence twice.

About `srand`:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

About `time`: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_time.htm

Why once:
[srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: You can also xor with the pid to add a bit more "randomness" to the seed

Comment: Also, it is good to output the seed to a log, so bugs can be reproduced

Answer (score 3):

Using `srand((unsigned)time(NULL))` to seed the random number generator is not reliable as `time()` returns the number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970.  This value only changes every second.  If you re-seed the generator during the same second, you will indeed get the same random sequence again.

You should use a source that changes faster:

```
srand((unsigned)clock());
```

Furthermore, re-seeding the generator is not recommended. The pseudo random number generator is crafted to produce a random sequence with certain properties. re-seeding the generator breaks this promise.